# Setting key while chaining in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine I have a `data.table` `DT` that has columns `a, b, c`. I want to filter rows based on `a` (say, select only those with value `"A"`), compute the sum of `b` by `c`. I can do this efficiently, using binary search for filtering, by

```
setkey(DT, a)
DT[.("A"), .(sum.B = sum(B)), by = .(C)]
```

What if then I want to filter rows based on the value of the newly obtained `sum.b`? If I want to keep rows where `sum.b` equals one of `c(3, 4, 5)`, I can do that by saying

```
DT[.("A"), .(sum.B = sum(B)), by = .(C)][sum.b %in% c(3, 4, 5)]
```

but the latter operation uses vector scan which is slow. Is there a way to set keys "on the fly" while chaining? Ideally I would have

```
DT[.("A"), .(sum.B = sum(B)), by = .(C)][??set sum.b as key??][.(c(3, 4, 5))]
```

where I don't know the middle step.

Comment: `setkey(DT[.("A"), .(sum.B = sum(B)), by = C], sum.B)[.(3:5)]`?

Comment: Does it avoid copying the result of the first operation?

Comment: Every time you use `[.data.table` you are creating a shallow copy AFIK, so not sure what you mean

Comment: David's way is the standard solution. If you don't care about column reordering, this is how you can do it within a chain: `DT[.("A"), .(sum.B = sum(B)), by = C][, .SD, keyby = sum.B][.(3:5)]`; and there is an active FR to simplify the middle by not having to type `.SD` (by simply making `.SD` the default value for `j`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle step you are asking in the question would be the following:

```
# unnamed args
DT[,.SD,,sum.b]
# named args
DT[j = .SD, keyby = sum.b]
# semi named
DT[, .SD, keyby = sum.b]
```

Yet you should benchmark it on your data as it *may* be slower than vector scan as you need to setkey.

It looks like eddi already provide that solution in comment. The FR mentioned by him is [data.table#1105](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1105).